# Angular $rootScope.$on Undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have the following in a controller.

```
$rootScope.$on('progressbarEvent', function (event, data) {
    $rootScope.progresscurrent = data.currentprogress;
    console.log('Event listening: ' + $rootScope.progresscurrent);
});

I have this in a factory service.
   $rootScope.$emit('progressbarEvent', dataFactory.currentprogress);
```

$on is returned undefined. Anyone knows the cause of this?

My controller is:

```
app.controller('indexcontroller', ['$rootScope','$scope', '$http', 'dataFactory',
       function ($scope,$http,$rootScope, dataFactory) {
```

Comment: Did you include `$rootScope`?

Comment: I updated the question to show first part of controller.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The order of dependencies has to be consistent with the array it was declared in:

```
app.controller('indexcontroller', ['$rootScope','$scope', '$http', 'dataFactory',
   function ($rootScope, $scope, $http, dataFactory) {
```

Comment: Can you clarify? My function is passing in the same order as the injector.

Comment: @Nate -- No it's not...You have $rootScope before $scope in the array, and $scope before $rootScope in the function

Comment: Sorry I was looking at the one you posted which was the fix. That fixed it!